# How to get the maxX of RelativeLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How to get the `maxX` of `RelativeLayout` in `Android`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call [getWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth()) on it

Comment: The [crutial point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) here is to know when to call the method.